How can I fix the visual basic "The project file could not be loaded" error?
I have tried to import a visual basic solution file from a different computer to my home computer, but when trying to load this file in visual studio, I received a message which reads "C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Documents\PayrollSystemV2.net\PayrollSystemV2.net.vbproj : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Documents\PayrollSystemV2.net\PayrollSystemV2.net.vbproj'. "
I emailed myself the file then downloaded it to my computer which is where this problem started. The project itself is to read/ write data from and into access database tables.
Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a way to solve it?
I have tried restarting the software and moving the file to a new location but neither have worked. It may be that I have missed something small but I'm quite stuck.

And does the file C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Documents\PayrollSystemV2.net\PayrollSystemV2.net.vbproj exist on your computer?  Does the same file exist somewhere else on your computer?  If the error is telling you that it can't find a file, why specifically do you think it should find that file?

Based on the file path you provided, it seems that the folder you imported might not be the root directory of the solution. I suggest you first check if the file mentioned in the error exists. If it's missing, try copying the entire folder containing the .sln file from your original computer to the new one. This should ensure a complete migration of the project.
